# Connecting react native to redis db

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redis, nosql

I'm trying to make a React Native application that needs to exchange data with a remote Redis server.

I've read on the web that I need to expose the redis API but I can't find anything about this.
The problem is that i keep getting results for react.js that is web and it's not what i'm searchng for.
Can someone write out a solution that i can adopt?

Comment: You should get an application server to work as an API for you react-native front-end. This server will exchange data with the Redis server and transform it back to JSON for you react-native.